# Use XML::LibXML to replace an XML node

Tags: xml, perl

Can someone help me please? I need to replace an XML node using Perl with the `XML::LibXML` module

This is the fragment of the XML file:

```
<utenti>
    <utente>
        <username>amministratore</username>
        <useremail>admin@email.com</useremail>
        <password>0000</password>
    </utente>
</utenti>
```

And I need to replace the value of the password.

In particular I have to find in the XML file the user with a particular username (given by the cookie `$userCookie`) and replace his password with the variable `$newPSW`.

I've tried this:

```
    my $psw = $doc->findnodes("/utenti/utente[username=\"$userCookie\"]/password");
    my $parent = $psw->parentNode;
    $parent->removeChild($psw);


    my $password = XML::LibXML::Element->new('password');
    $password->appendText( $newPSW );
    $parent->appendChild($password);
```

but everytime the browser give me the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "parentNode" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList"
```

It seems to no find any method I use.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a `XML::LibXML::NodeList` as result. And this object has no function `parentNode`. You have to  get the first element of the array and then call the method `parentNode` on it.

The first object will be an object of class `XML::LibXML::Node` and this has a funtion `parentNode`.

for more details see the documentation of [XML::LibXML::Node](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod)

```
my $psw = $doc->findnodes("/utenti/utente[username=\"$userCookie\"]/password");
my $parent = $psw->[0]->parentNode;
$parent->removeChild($psw->[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `$psw` is an `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object, not just a single node -- although it should be a list of one node

The simplest solution here is to use a list assignment to grab just the first -- and hopefully only -- element in the list

It's also neater to change the string delimiter if you have embedded double quotes

Like this

```
my ($psw) = $doc->findnodes(qq</utenti/utente[username="$userCookie"]/password>);
```

Answer (score 3):

[XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), can make your life easier:

```
set /utenti/utente[username="amministratore"]/password $newPSW ;
```

Answer (score 2):

update: you don't need to mess with the parent to change the contents of a node

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML 1.70; ## for load_html/load_xml/location
my $xml = q{<a><b><c>old password</c></b></a>};
my $dom = XML::LibXML->new(qw/ recover 2 /)->load_xml(
#~     location => $filepath_or_http,
    string => $xml,
);
my $password = $dom->findnodes('//c')->get_node(0);
$password->removeChildNodes;
$password->appendText('new password');
print "$dom";
__END__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a><b><c>new password</c></b></a>
```

You could even ask for parent via xpath :) and using list context findnodes returns a list of nodes instead of a ...NodeList object

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML 1.70; ## for load_html/load_xml/location
my $xml = q{<a><b><c></c></b></a>};
my $dom = XML::LibXML->new(qw/ recover 2 /)->load_xml(
#~     location => $filepath_or_http,
    string => $xml,
);
my( $parent ) = $dom->findnodes('//c/..');
print $parent->nodePath;
__END__
/a/b
```